# Прокрутка страницы наверх не работает как надо

Tags: jquery

Нужно прокручивать страницу немного вниз при скролле мыши вниз, к определенной позиции
   `var scrollHeight = $('.header').height() + $('.main-slider').height();`
и скроллить страницу к самому верху, если при скролле вверх окно достигает этой же позиции

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header main-page-header">header</div>
    <div class="main-slider">main-slider</div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var scrollHeight = $('.header').height() + $('.main-slider').height();

if ($('.header').hasClass('main-page-header')) {
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {

    if (lastScrollTop === 0) {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: scrollHeight
        }, 600);
    }
}

if (scrollTop < lastScrollTop) {

    if (scrollTop < scrollHeight) {

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
    }
}
lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});

}
```

Первая часть скрипта, скролл вниз к определенной позиции, работает как надо, а при прокрутке наверх, когда окно достигает нужного места, страница прокручивается к самому верху, но потом ее становиться невозможно прокрутить вниз.

http://jsfiddle.net/qwvn7vpo/7/

Как сделать чтобы код работал правильно при прокрутке вверх?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто не обрабатывайте события scroll пока идет анимация,

```js
var scrollHeight = $('.header').height() + $('.main-slider').height(),
  $htmlBody = $("html, body");

if ($('.header').hasClass('main-page-header')) {
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($htmlBody.is(':animated')) { // <-ТУТ
      return;
    };
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
      console.log(1);
      if (lastScrollTop === 0) {

        $htmlBody.animate({
          scrollTop: scrollHeight
        }, 600);
      }
    }

    if (scrollTop < lastScrollTop) {

      if (scrollTop < scrollHeight) {
        scrollTop = 0;
        console.log(2);
        $htmlBody.animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
      }
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
  });
}
```

```css
.main {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
.main-slider {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="header main-page-header">header</div>
  <div class="main-slider">main-slider</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, опять же первая прокрутка вниз и первая прокрутка вверх отрабатывают нормально, а потом снова не дает прокрутить страницу вниз http://jsfiddle.net/qwvn7vpo/8/

Comment: у меня все отлично работает в вашем fiddle, какой у вас браузер ? (мой chrome)

Comment: в firefox заметно, поставьте `scrollTop=0 ` для scrollTop < scrollHeight

Comment: у меня в Хроме как раз не работало. но со `scrollTop=0` теперь все работает как нужно, большое спасибо за помощь.